# Closest date to current date / Structure C

Tags: arrays, c, date, numbers, structure

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The task is:
Write a date structure consisting of three fields, day, month and year. Load n dates from standard input, and specify and write the closest date to the current date.

I tried it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100
typedef struct date
{
    int day,month,year;
}DATE;
int main()
{
int i,n,min,min2,d,d1,l,l1,m,m1,m2,g,g1,g2;
DATE plgn[MAX];
printf("Enter as many dates you want:");
scanf("%d",&n);
while(n<1 || n>MAX)
{
    printf("Enter as many dates you want:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(i==0)
    {
        printf("Enter the current date:\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&plgn[i].day,&plgn[i].month,&plgn[i].year);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter %d. date:\n",i);
        scanf("%d %d %d",&plgn[i].day,&plgn[i].month,&plgn[i].year);
    }
}
min=1;
d=plgn[0].year-plgn[min].year;
m=plgn[min].year;
m1=plgn[min].month;
m2=plgn[min].day;
min2=1;
d1=plgn[0].month-plgn[min2].month;
g1=plgn[min2].month;
g=plgn[min2].year;
g2=plgn[min2].day;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(plgn[0].year==plgn[i].year)
   {
       l1=plgn[0].month-plgn[i].month;
       if(l1<d1)
       {
           d1=l1;
           g1=plgn[i].month;
           g=plgn[i].year;
           g2=plgn[i].day;
       }
       printf("%d.%d.%d",g2,g1,g);
       break;
   }
   else if(plgn[0].godina!=plgn[i].godina)
   {
       l=plgn[0].year-plgn[i].year;
       if(l>d)
       {
           d=l;
           m=plgn[i].year;
           m1=plgn[i].month;
           m2=plgn[i].day;
       }
       printf("%d.%d.%d",m2,m1,m);
       break;
   }

 }


}
```

After this I realized that my code has a lot of logical errors. I am interested in whether someone can explain the logic to me in order to do this task in the simplest way, because I have complicated it a lot.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'll start: If I want 2 dates, your program asks for today's date and 1 more date. I'd expect todays's date and 2 more dates.

Comment: That is not the biggest problem, but thanks !

Comment: Even better: your program determines today's date on its own...

Comment: The biggest problem is how to determine the closest date to today's date, as I wrote the code there is a problem, because the program mixes the year and month

Comment: You should compare each date to the current date, after you save all the dates in array, as you did, iterate over each date and and update the minimum (you can for example convert all to days and keep the min days) keep in mind that close date may be before of after the date and each month have different number of days )

Comment: Using standard C functions, i would convert each day/month/year value to a `time_t` value for midnight on the day with `mktime()`.  Then you can compare the different time values.  Use the same time each day.  Midday works as well as midnight as long as you are consistent.